# Kernel died while using itertools.combinations

Tags: python, kernel, combinations, python-itertools

I am using `itertools.combinations` to generate all possible combinations of elements of a list. However kernel always dies after 2 minutes. I assume it's a memory issue. Is there any other efficient way to produce all possible combinations and store it in some data structure?

```
total = ['E', 'ENE', 'ESE', 'N', 'NNE', 'NNW', 'NW', 'S', 'SE', 'SSE',
       'SSW', 'SW', 'W', 'WNW', 'WSW', 'station_0', 'station_1',
       'station_2', 'station_3', 'station_4', 'station_5', 'station_6',
       'station_7', 'station_8', 'station_9', 'station_10', 'year',
       'month', 'day', 'hour', 'SO2', 'NO2', 'CO', 'O3', 'TEMP', 'PRES',
       'DEWP', 'RAIN', 'WSPM']            

total_combinations = []           

for i in range(2,len(total)+1):
    current_comb = list(combinations(total,i))
    total_combinations = total_combinations + current_comb
```

Comment: you could store it in a big file and just read from it when you need it. edit: well, maybe not, it would be over 0.5 TB if you would save it in a file :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my maths is correct, you have **549755813848** total combinations!

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> n = len(total)
>>> sum(factorial(n) / factorial(r) / factorial(n-r) for r in range(2,n+1))
549755813848.0
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> The number of items returned is n! / r! / (n-r)! when 0 <= r <= n or
>   zero when r > n.

So no, it won't be possible to store them all in memory using  a 'normal' computer. You'll have to find a way to solve your problem while processing each item separately.